# re: my Trust Wallet migration from iPhone #1 to #2 which recognizes seed phrase but did not transfer 3 active accounts (eth, btc, $link)

Tags: recovery, trustwallet

1. iPhone #1 broken/no access - no prior attempts were made to backup TrustWallet data to iCloud,
2. iPhone #2 insurance replacement - downloaded TrustWallet from AppStore via iCloud >  of which having recognized the original seed phrase,
3. issue #1:  my TrustWallet contains 3 crypto accounts (ETH,BTC,$LINK)- none of which showed up,
4. issue #2:  as a result, my private & public key(s) not available - only seed phrase,
5. Question #1:  Is there a search protocol or wallet - and or other abilities to retrieve all 3 crypto accounts using a seed phrase ?
6. Question #2:  I originally purchased and held only BTC in TrustWallet via CASHapp Wallet of which transaction details/contract are available  - ***Would this be a plausible first link for recovery in the chain of events ?***

Comment: Are you sure the seed phrase is correct ? TrustWallet is a non-custodial wallet, meaning that they don't store information about your wallet. Everything should be deduced from the seed phrase. I think when adding the seed phrase it allows to select which coins to show, you can change the selection afterward.